# Is there an algorithms to detect refills into a water tank by the changes of water tank level

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write some codes to detect refills of a water tank over a period of time.

The outputs required would be the start/end time and volume of every refill detected.

The input I have is a continuous stream of Water Tank Level data points i.e. 1,440 of them for a 24 hours period, one minute each.

And typically there will never be two consecutive refills. After each refill, there will be a period of water consumption before another refill can take place.

The current design of my algorithm goes like this:

1. Sort the 1,440 data points by date/time, to start from oldest to newest.
2. Load the sorted 1,440 data points into an array.
3. Start with the first data points. Let's call it S.
4. Compare the water level of S with S+1.
5. If S+1 is lower than S, means it's on "consumption" mode.
6. Repeat the comparison of S+1 with S+2, then S+2 with S+3 so on, until I come to a point where S+N returns a water level that is higher than S+N-1, means a "refill" mode has started.
7. Save S+N-1 as the "Bottom".
8. Save S+N as the "Start of Refill". Let's call it R.
9. Now I need to find when and where the "refill" stop.
10. So I will compare R with R+1, then R+1 with R+2 and so on, and repeat as long as R+N is higher than R+N-1 (as that means the refilling is still ongoing) and stop if R+N is lower or equal to R+N-1 (as that means the refilling has stopped).
11. Save R+N-1 as the "Top".
12. Subtract the "Top" and "Bottom" and the difference is the volume refilled into the tank. The date/time of "Bottom" is the start and date/time of "Top" is the end of that refill event.

This works perfectly fine; but I realise it can't manage noise in the data. For whatever reason, the reading from the tank will have certain degree of fluctuations.

When an actual refill is taking place between R and R+N-1, it's not 100% guarantee that all the data points (let's call them D) between R (start of refill) and R+N-1 (end of refill) are always higher than its previous one. Illustration below:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,**12,11,13**,14,15,16,**17,16,16,18**,19,20]

If I use my algorithm on the above dataset, it will mistaken "12" as my end of refill, because the next data point is "11" which is lower than 12.

Any suggestion on how can I improve my algorithm to check and eliminate such noises in the data?

Comment: My first suggestion is to share your data (you can use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar) so other folks can try their ideas. My second is to share your code so other folks can check it over and assist you better. My third is to have a read on denoising data and smoothing. Hopefully you'll get a good solution then. Please also add a language tag.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Let me try to do some reading on denoising data and smoothing :)